# unzip Zip files from local storage in angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2, jszip

I am working with Angular 2. I have a zip file on my local computer. i want to upload it and see the data inside it. The zip file is of about 100 MB.The folder contains different folder inside it.
I am using

```
<input id="addedFile" ion-input type="file" accept=".zip" #fileInput >
```

to input the file.
I am able to get filename file size etc but not the content.
Any help is appreciated 
Thank You.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-zip maybe. Haven't used it myself

Comment: Also isn't local storage constrained to something like 5MB? PouchDB maybe.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406730/localforage-size-limit-for-an-ionic-mobile-app

Comment: You can use some library like https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/ to open zip files in the browser. But you won't be able to store this amount of data in the localStorage, as @JGFMK mentioned. Anyway, I think that you will have memory issues when handling a .zip file of this size in the client side.